# how to fix loading a scene in unity

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, scene

The script is to move to the next scene when the "new game" button is pressed. The sound effect plays, but it does not go to the next scene and I get this error :ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source. I know you have to type null, but I don't know where.

```html
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SoundManagerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static AudioClip clikSound;
    static AudioSource audioScr;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        clikSound = Resources.Load<AudioClip> ("clik");
         audioScr = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
    public static void PlaySound(string clip)
    {
        switch (clip)
        {
            case "clik":
                audioScr.PlayOneShot(clikSound);
                    break;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class MeinMenu : MonoBehaviour
{

    static AudioSource audioScr;
    public void NewGame()
    {
        
        SoundManagerScript.PlaySound("clik");
         DontDestroyOnLoad(audioScr.gameObject);
        SceneManager.LoadScene("level 1");
        
    }
    public void LoadGame()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SavedScene"));
    }
    


}
```

Comment: None of the code you've provided has anything to do with scene loading.

Comment: Is the click file inside your Asset folder?

Comment: @KiynL I added another script to my question

Answer (score 0):

Possible mistake: The scenes in the build are not there.

Go to **File > Build Settings**

[image]

Drag and drop your scenes in your Scenes folder into the **Scenes in Build**.

Comment: I have it already done